# Adding GET input to my resourceful controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller

Using Laravel 4 to create a "Read-it-Later" application just for testing purposes.
I'm able to successfully store a URL and Description into my application using the following curl command:

```
curl -d 'url=http://testsite.com&description=For Testing' readitlater.local/api/v1/url
```

I'm interested in using GET to accomplish the same thing but by passing my variables in a URL (e.g. **readitlater.local/api/v1/url?url=testsite.com?description=For%20Testing**)

Here is my UrlController segment:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $url = new Url;
    $url->url = Request::get('url');
    $url->description = Request::get('description');

    $url->save();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'urls' => $urls->toArray()),
        200
    );
}
```

Here is my Url model:

```
<?php

class Url extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'urls';

}
```

I read through the Laravel docs on input types but I'm not certain how to apply that to my current controller: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't apply what you correctly linked to...Use `Input::get()` to fetch anything from GET or POST, and the `Request` class to get info on the current request. Are you looking for something like this?

```
        public function store()
        {
            $url = new Url; // I guess this is your Model
            $url->url = Request::url();
            $url->description = Input::get('description');
            $url->save();

            return Response::json(array(
                'error' => false,
                'urls' => Url::find($url->id)->toArray(), 
    /* Not sure about this. You want info for the current url? 
    (you already have them...no need to query the DB) or you want ALL the urls? 
    In this case, use Url::all()->toArray()
    */
                200
            );
        }
```

Comment: The return Response was my attempt at a confirmation when data is sent over curl. You're right, for the URL method, it is unnecessary. I added my Url model in my original question as well in case that helps. SO, you're saying all I have to do is change Request::get('description'); to Input::get('description'); and I'm able to pull variables from my URL?

Comment: Exaclty, that's what `Input::get()` is for. And as for the model, since it seems you're fetching all the urls, use as I suggested in code comments: `Url::all()->toArray()`